# Adding array of value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm asking this question again and hope I get the answer this time, I have an array of number that adds and subtract on button click which works with`onclick` and a function created. I will like the sum up of the array `21998` and `11999` when this same button is click and will like to display the value in `<p id=""sumTotal></p>` find screenshot of what my array looks like:

[image]

I have an `onClick` function that multiple `quantity` with total every time `-` and `+` are clicked. I will like the sum-up of `21,998` and `11,999` when `-` and `+` are clicked. Below is what my HTML code and PHP script look like:

```
<p id = "sumTotal"></p>
    <table class="table table-cart table-mobile">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <? for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['img_src']);$i++){ ?>
        <tr>
    <td class="price-col" id="<? echo $_SESSION['id'][$i].'_price' ?>" >&#8358;<?php echo $_SESSION['price'][$i] ?></td>

            <td>
                <div onclick="clickMe(<?php echo  $_SESSION['id'][$i]; ?>)">
                    <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-decimals="0" required id = "<? echo $_SESSION['id'][$i].'_quantityCount' ?>">
                </div><!-- End .cart-product-quantity -->
            </td>
            <td id = "<? echo $_SESSION['id'][$i].'_totalPrice' ?>">&#8358;<?php echo $_SESSION['price'][$i] ?></td>
        </tr>
    
    <?
        }
    ?>
<tbody>
    </table>
```

And my javascript `onclick` looks like below code:

```
    <script>
        function clickMe(id) {
           var price = document.getElementById(id+"_price").innerHTML;
           let finalPrice =  price.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
           var quantity = document.getElementById(id+"_quantityCount").value;
           var totalPrice = quantity * finalPrice;
           document.getElementById(id+"_totalPrice").innerHTML = "\u20A6"+totalPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");


          
        }
    </script>
```

I will like to get the sum total of `21,998` and `11,999`to `<p id = "sumTotal"></p>`

Comment: I don't see id+price in your markup.  Your PHP script will output the price as total price, when it should be doing a calculation of itemprice * quantity.  Even if you change something in javascript, the totalprice will get reset to the item price when the page is rendered.  I also don't know why you have such a complicated regex, when all you need to do to convert a number string to a float is remove commas.  I would strongly suggest you save the currency in a separate attribute both on the backend and the frontend.  Then you aren't trying to strip it off the number.

Comment: Output the currency character in your markup using a span, and have your numeric value in its own span.

Comment: Sorry I just updated my question with it.

Comment: I will be looking forward to your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself, at first on the load of the page I sum up the all prices to get my initial `sumTotal` and did that in PHP with `$subTotal_sum = array_sum( str_replace(",", "", $_SESSION['price']));`. So `<p id = "sumTotal"></p>` will be `<p id = "sumTotal">echo array_sum( str_replace(",", "", $_SESSION['price']));</p>` And inside my javascript I made the changes with the script, I get the value of `sumTotal` subtracted it from `Price` and add the `sumTotal` and new price after `+` or `-` to get the new `sumTotal` below is my update code:

```
  <p id = "sumTotal">$subTotal_sum = array_sum( str_replace(",", "", $_SESSION['price']));</p>
    <table class="table table-cart table-mobile">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <? for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['img_src']);$i++){ ?>
        <tr>
    <td class="price-col" id="<? echo $_SESSION['id'][$i].'_price' ?>" >&#8358;<?php echo $_SESSION['price'][$i] ?></td>

            <td>
                <div onclick="clickMe(<?php echo  $_SESSION['id'][$i]; ?>)">
                    <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" data-decimals="0" required id = "<? echo $_SESSION['id'][$i].'_quantityCount' ?>">
                </div><!-- End .cart-product-quantity -->
            </td>
            <td id = "<? echo $_SESSION['id'][$i].'_totalPrice' ?>">&#8358;<?php echo $_SESSION['price'][$i] ?></td>
        </tr>
    
    <?
        }
    ?>
<tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        function clickMe(id) {
            var sumTotal = document.getElementById("sumTotal").value;
           var price = document.getElementById(id+"_price").innerHTML;

           var initialSumTotal = parseInt(sumTotal) - parseInt(price);
           
           let finalPrice =  price.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
           var quantity = document.getElementById(id+"_quantityCount").value;
           var totalPrice = quantity * finalPrice;
           document.getElementById(id+"_totalPrice").innerHTML = "\u20A6"+totalPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

            var sumTotal= parseInt(initialSumTotal)+parseInt(totalPrice);
         
         // parsing the value to display on sub total
          document.getElementById("sumTotal").value ="\u20A6"+sumTotal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        
          
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in the end of **clickMe** function.

```
function total() {
  const priceElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="_totalPrice"]');
  return [...priceElements].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr.innerText, 0);
}
```

Comment: How do I show this result in ```<p id = "sumTotal"></p>``` ?

Comment: I tired ```var colloer = [...priceElements].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr.innerText, 0);
  alert(colloer);``` but alert is ```0```

Comment: Insert data in <p> tag: 
const result = [...priceElements].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr.innerText, 0);
document.querySelector('#sumTotal').innerHTML = result;

Comment: It alerts 0 because your array (priceElements) is empty I guess.
Probably I wrote wrong selector. Check if "id" of your elements ends with "_totalPrice"
Fix the selector (in document.querySelectorAll) to match the actual endings of your element IDs in DOM.